# Visualise data under Tecplot

Tags: fluid-dynamics, plotting

I have a set of data that I need to visualise under Tecplot, the file format is for example:

```
X  U1   U2        
1  0    0         
2  0.1  0.01     
3  0.15 0.01     
4  0.12 0.015  
.  .    .    
.  .    .    
.  .    .
```

I need to display X and U1, and ideally U2 on the same graphic.

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE! Please give a (short!) example of the format of the data you have, otherwise it's impossible to answer your question.

Comment: The [Tecplot user forum](http://tecplottalk.com/) might actually be more appropriate for this. Have you already tried to find an answer there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the content of a sample Tecplot data file. Data is one dimension i.e. U vs. X for 20 points. I was using a C program to solve my equations and at the end of my program, I had a small subroutine which writes this information into a .PLT or .DAT file which is then used in Tecplot. I think this should suffice for very basic data plotting. If there is anything specific, I would like you to post that in your question specifically.

```
VARIABLES="X","U"

ZONE  F=POINT

I=20

0.00000000  0.00000000

5.00000000  0.28632834

10.00000000 0.52683960

15.00000000 0.68127329

20.00000000 0.72938137

25.00000000 0.67444474

30.00000000 0.54886950

35.00000000 0.40325212

40.00000000 0.28895415

45.00000000 0.24889311

50.00000000 0.30863131

55.00000000 0.46400776

60.00000000 0.67566198

65.00000000 0.93921596

70.00000000 1.29542423

75.00000000 1.51374208

80.00000000 1.35904516

85.00000000 1.01646862

90.00000000 0.54498717

95.00000000 0.00000000
```

Comment: How can I display multiple variables, let us say X vs U1 and U2 on the same graphic ?

Comment: In that case, you can have two data files, one for U1 and one for U2. Suppose, if you display U1 first in Tecplot. Then navigate to File and then select Load Data Files and add the second file to the existing plot. If you still can not see, go to "Mapping Style" and create a new map with U2 as the variable on y-axis. That is how you can do both of them in the same plot.